# AdMob adverts not showing in Emulator - Android App

Tags: java, android, admob, emulation

I have been trying to get AdMob adverts to show in the Android app emulator. I am using Eclipse, and when I click on the "Graphical Design" it shows a white rectangle (where the advert would be) and says "Ads by Google".

However, when I run the advert on the Emulator, no advert appears.

I followed the guide on the Google development pages word for word and I thought it would work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is my code:

In XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/beach"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="MY ADD ID (it's filled in in my code)" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

In the activity:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TEST_DEVICE_ID = "INSERT_YOUR_TEST_DEVICE_ID_HERE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // The "loadAdOnCreate" and "testDevices" XML attributes no longer available.
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")

        .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try By putting this line of code in to yours:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)    // remove if in real time use
        .addTestDevice(getDeviceId())       // remove if in real time use
        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I had this in my code. What do you mean by real time? Does that mean if I am testing it?

Comment: It means if you are testing then use this code otherwise If you are going to upload the apk then remove this commented code.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a real device to test it on, I can only use the emulator. Should adverts appear on the emulator?

Comment: yes definitely it appears in emulator. For more understanding post your whole code.

Comment: Sure thing, I have edited my main post with the code. Thanks for your help :)